# How to disallow my customer to not purchase any product from my site magento 2

Tags: magento2, orders, enable-disable

For temporary purpose, i want none of my customer should place order on my site. They can browse on my website but cant place any order. How can i do that in magento 2

Answer (score 1):

Store >> Configuration >> Sales >> Checkout,in Checkout Options disable Enable Onepage Checkout

Or

You can go into Store >> Configuration >> Sales  >> Shipping Methods, for turning off all shipping methods

Or

Go into Store >> Configuration >> Sales  >> Payment Methods, for turning off all payment methods